# How to fix a Gulp generated file being too large

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, webpack

I am trying to use Gulp to generate a file,

gulphile.js

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(mix => {
  mix.sass('app.scss')
     .webpack('app.js');
});
```

app.js

```
 window._ = require('lodash');
 window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
 require('bootstrap-sass');

 window.Vue = require('vue');
 require('vue-resource');
```

When I run the command `gulp watch` Gulp generates a file with a very big size (about 3mb), and the file does not look like it is minimized.

It looks something like this:

```
 /******/   // Load entry module and return exports
 /******/   return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 11);
 /******/ })
 /************************************************************************/
 /******/ ([
 /* 0 */
 /***/ function(module, exports) {

  eval("var g;\r\n\r\n// This works in non-strict 
  mode\r\ng = (function() {   return this; })();\r\n\r\ntry {\r\n\t// This     
  works if eval is allowed (see CSP)\r\n\tg = g || Function(\"return this\")
  () || (1,eval)(\"this\");\r\n} catch(e) {\r\n\t// This works if the window refer
```

How can I fix it to generate the file correctly minimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--production` option to run the tasks to minimize the css and js files.

```
gulp --production
```

This option works with `watch`, as well:

```
gulp watch --production
```

Comment: @patricus  i am also having a similar issue but in my case i have run 'gulp --production' but my app.js file is still as large as 600kb...pls what can i do to solve it ?